Get queue/message details similar to RequestStack for API calls when logging
I am using a monolog.processor as explained in https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging/processors.html to get some information about the request. See this working example:
<?php

namespace App\Logger;

use Monolog\LogRecord;
use Monolog\Processor\ProcessorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

readonly class RequestDetailsProcessor implements ProcessorInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private RequestStack              $requestStack,
    ) {
    }

    // method is called for each log record; optimize it to not hurt performance
    public function __invoke(LogRecord $record): LogRecord
    {
        $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
        $record->extra['functionName'] = $request?->attributes->get('_controller');
        return $record;
    }
}

services.yaml
App\Logger\RequestDetailsProcessor:
    arguments: [ "@request_stack" ]
    tags:
        - { name: monolog.processor, handler: main }

This works great so far and gives me some beautiful output in my logging system for API calls:
{
    "timestamp": "2024-10-09T11:58:44.117984+02:00",
    "message": "foobar",
    "level": "info",
    "extra":
    {
        "functionName": "App\\Controller\\MyController::myMethod"
    }
}

However this class is also called for logs in my Symfony Messenger where the requestStack is empty. I'd like to enrich my messenger's logging to contain the transport's name/message handlers class name/ (everything will work) in such cases. Is there any similar thing like @request_stack that I could inject to get some details about the message/handler instead of the request? E.g. wished output
{
    "timestamp": "2024-10-09T11:58:44.117984+02:00",
    "message": "foobar",
    "level": "info",
    "extra":
    {
        "functionName": "App\\MessageHandler\\MyHandler::handle"
    }
}

